# Are these statements functionally equivalent?

Tags: javascript

As far as I can tell they function the same, but I wanted to make sure. I would like to use the latter statement as it is less code and seems more efficient.

```
function updateRunningTotals(taxExempt, discType, discAmt){
  if (typeof taxExempt === 'undefined') { taxExempt = false; }
  taxExempt = taxExempt || false;
}
```

I have been using the `if`, but I have seen the latter statement in some open source projects. Do they basically do the same thing? Any performance benefit?

EDIT: taxExempt, in this scenario may not always be passed in.

Comment: If `taxExempt` is an optional argument, it could be neater to have it as the final parameter.

Comment: Ya, good call, not sure why I have it first anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> if (typeof taxExempt === 'undefined') { taxExempt = false; }
```

In this case, *textExempt* will only be set to false if its value is *undefined*.

```
> taxExempt = taxExempt || false;
```

In this case, *taxExempt* will be set to false if its value coerces to false (i.e. [*ToBoolean(taxExempt)*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) returns false), e.g. it might be null, 0, false, NaN, '' or undefined.

So no, they are not functionally equivalent. And choosing the second only because it's less code is not sound logic. The first is clearer logic for most.

Comment: I'd say both lines assign some default value to `taxExempt`. What of those are more relevant actually depends on how this variable will be used later.

Comment: I wasn't choosing *just* because it is less code. I would only do so if they were functionally equivalent, which obviously they are not.

Comment: @raina77ow— *taxExempt* has a default value of *undefined* by being included in the parameter list. It's not clear to my why a variable with a value of *undefined* might need to be re-assigned a value of *false* without seeing how it is used later. The answer is only in the context of the OP.

Comment: Aren't both statements equivalent to simply `taxExempt = !!taxExempt`?

Comment: @RGraham—the second is, the first isn't.

Comment: @RGraham, even second one isn't for anything not falsy and not `true` (for example for `1`, "blah").

Comment: @RobG, The reason it needs to be reassigned is because the variable is not sent in all situations and I need to test for it later `if(!taxExempt){`. Should I just send it in every case? Probably make code easier to read.

Comment: @KrunchMuffin—if it's supposed to be boolean then *undefined* and *false* are essentially the same, so `if (taxExempt)` will do. If it's "not passed" then probably nor are the other arguments.

Answer (score 3):

They are not equivalent.

```
if (typeof taxExempt === 'undefined') { taxExempt = false; }
```

This statement would only change `undefined` to false.

```
taxExempt = taxExempt || false;
```

This one would change also `null`, `""`, `0` or anything that is considered false in boolean context.

```
taxExempt = !!taxExempt;
taxExempt = Boolean(taxExempt);
```

These two are equivalent statements that not only map "falsy" values to `false`, but also "truthy" ones to `true`.

All shown statements are equivalent if `taxExempt` is either `undefined`, `false` or `true`.